# Dividing raster cell into smaller cells and evenly spreading values to new cells using ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, arcgis-10.4

I need to divide/split raster cells into smaller cells (i.e. coarse to fine resolution) and then evenly assign values of the original cell to the finer cells. For example - focusing on a single cell for simplicity - I have a 5km x 5km cell with a value of say 100. I need to split that cell into 25 1km cells (5km x 5km) and evenly distribute the value of 100 across the 25 cells, meaning each 1km cell gets a value of 4 (100/25 = 4).

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.4.1.

Comment: Use the resample tool to create your raster with a finer resolution, then run it through the divide tool.

Comment: Thanks! This will solve my problem.